# Deployment of website

Tags: asp.net

I deployed my website into IIS..I created virtual directory and gave an alias 'a'..but when I open the site in IE or Mozilla, it says 'Access is denied'..i write http://localhost/a/Login.aspx
Server Error in '/a' Application.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you setup the relevant permissions in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Seems most likely your web application is trying to run the app using the wrong .NET framework version, that got me the first time. But it could be pretty much anything.

You may want to set up visual studio to debug on the local (but external) IIS server instead of cassini (the debug server built in to visual studio 2005 and up) You can do this in the project settings but I don't remember the exact procedure. It's easy enough to figure out though. Visual studio should help you set up your web.config file to allow debugging. You'll be able to get a stacktrace error page and even break on exceptions.